# Dynamic header in \csvreader

Tags: tabularray, csvsimple-13

The input CSV file has a variable number of columns - either 3 or 4. The data should be added to the second row in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th columns, so the data above will span over a different number of columns, according to the input CSV file.

It is necessary to define a dynamic header that will match the input CSV data.

I have an example of a Latex code, which generated an error that I could not fix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{file3.csv}
  a,b,c
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file4.csv}
 a,b,c,d
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GenerateHeader}{m}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1} { & }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff  

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\InputCSV}[1]{%
\readdef{#1}\filedata%
\csvreader[%
no head,
tabularray={colspec={X[1,c,m]
*{\ncols}{X[1,c,m]} X[1,c,m]X[1,c,m]},
hlines,vlines,
width=\textwidth,
colsep=2.5pt,
rowsep=4.5pt,
row{1-2}={c,m,fg=black,bg=black!10,font=\bfseries\small},
cell{1}{1}={r=2}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries,bg=black!10},
cell{1}{2}={c=\ncols}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries,bg=black!10},
cell{1}{\ncols+2}={c=2}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries,bg=black!10},
},
table head=Sample&Span over 3 or 4 columns 
%
\GenerateHeader{\ncols}
Last& \\
]{#1}
{}{%
\ifnumequal{\ncols}{4}{%
   Name  &\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcoliv&Result & Erros 
                        }{%
\ifnumequal{\ncols}{3}{%
   Name  &\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&Result & Erros
                        }{}%                              
                        }
  }%
}

\InputCSV{file3.csv}

\bigskip
```

The file consists of \ncols{} columns.

\end{document}

This is the expected appearance of the output tables

[image]
[image]

Any advice and Latex example would be of great help.
Packages csvsimple-l3 and tabularrai should be used in Latex code!